# Assistance with if statements in swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to programming and was trying to figure out how I get `else if` statements to read my variable and range operator in Swift? I cant use a `switch` and need to use `if` statements.

```
var Fahrenheit = 10
if Fahrenheit <0 {
    print("Too Cold for Outdoors")
    }
else if Fahrenheit == 0 - 20 {
    print("Very Cold Weather");
    }
else if Fahrenheit == 21 - 40{
    print("Cold")
    }
else if Fahrenheit == 41 - 60{
    print("Normal");
    }
else if Fahrenheit == 60 - 80{
    print("Nice");
    }
else if Fahrenheit == 81 - 90{
    print("Warm");
    }
else if Fahrenheit >90 {
    print("Hot");
    }
```

Comment: Hey Gourdrik, welcome to the sight. `0 - 20` is not a range, it's an expression that evaluates to `-20` (it's just plain old subtraction). So `Fahrenheit == 0 - 20` is actually checking `Fahrenheit == -20`, specifically.

Comment: Ranges in Swift are spelt using `...` or `..<`. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID73 I always strongly recommend people read that book (the Swift programming language guide) cover-to-cover. It's exceptionally well written, and will save a lot of frustration as compared to trying to guess-and-check your way through the process of learning the language syntax.

Comment: Why can't you use switch? This is a perfect use case.

Comment: sorry english my second language, i tried 3periods but it told me: Int not convertible to Bool, and binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'ClosedRange<Int>'

Comment: The challenge was to create 1 with switch statement, and 1 with if statement, i have done the switch statement, but dont understand where im going wrong with if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `...` operator creates a [`ClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange), and `ClosedRange` has a [`contains` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/1784630-contains).

```
var fahrenheit = 10

if fahrenheit < 0 {
    print("Too Cold for Outdoors")
} else if (0 ... 20).contains(fahrenheit) {
    print("Very Cold Weather");
} else if (21 ... 40).contains(fahrenheit) {
    print("Cold")
} else etc. etc. etc
```

If you don't want to use `...`, you can write explicit comparisons. Note that because we're checking the ranges in ascending order, we only need to test the upper bound of each range to get the correct answer:

```
var fahrenheit = 10

if fahrenheit < 0 {
    print("Too Cold for Outdoors")
} else if fahrenheit <= 20 {
    print("Very Cold Weather");
} else if fahrenheit <= 40  {
    print("Cold")
} else etc. etc. etc.
```

But if you really want to test both bounds of each range, you can do so like this:

```
var fahrenheit = 10

if fahrenheit < 0 {
    print("Too Cold for Outdoors")
} else if 0 <= fahrenheit && fahrenheit <= 20 {
    print("Very Cold Weather");
} else if 20 < fahrenheit && fahrenheit <= 40  {
    print("Cold")
} else etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: In languages without ranges like C and C++, I've fallen in love with the style like `20 < fahrenheit && fahrenheit <= 40`. I can't look people the same when I see them write `20 < fahrenheit && 40 > fahrenheit`